# Submit not working due to special char

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My action link is as

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "UserProfile", new { id= Server.UrlEncode(item.UserCd) })"</a>
```

Sample ID= Testing\Simon

With encode, my url will look like this

```
http://localhost/Home/UserProfile/Edit/Testing%5Simon
```

It work fine in display, but when click submit, page prompt out **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**, I check the error, it see like web had change the way it take the data

```
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/Home/UserProfile/Edit/Testing/Simon
```

I not able to debug it as it never go to the controller method

How to cater with this matter?

Comment: In your Sample ID did you mean `Testing/Simon` or did it really change the backslash to a forward slash?

Comment: yes, it change it to forward slash, no idea why, and made my submit failed

Comment: What if you take out the `Server.UrlEncode` and just set id to `item.UserCd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the routeconfig is the main core of the asp.net MVC, after study through different example on net

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "userProfile",
                url: "UserProfile/Edit/{id}/{id1}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserProfile", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id1 = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I create a route as this, not sure if this is the correct way

I take out the encode and decode from the code

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "UserProfile", new { id=item.UserCd })" ></a>
```

It work fine now